# Saving keras configuration with custom metric function to JSON

Tags: python, json, keras

I am trying to save my configuration for a Keras model. I would like to be able to read the configuration from the file to be able to reproduce the training.

Before implementing a custom metric in a function I could just do it the way shown below without the `mean_pred`. Now I am running into the problem `TypeError: Object of type 'function' is not JSON serializable`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142062/get-function-name-as-a-string-in-python) I read that it is possible to get the function name as string by `custom_metric_name = mean_pred.__name__`. I would like to not only be able to save the name, but to be able to save a reference to the function if possible.

Perhaps I should as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423214/how-to-save-a-configuration-file-python-file-io) also think about not just storing my configuration in the .py file but using `ConfigObj`. Unless this would solve my current problem I would implement this later.

Minimum working example of problem:

```
import keras.backend as K
import json

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

config = {'epochs':500,
          'loss':{'class':'categorical_crossentropy'},
          'optimizer':'Adam',
          'metrics':{'class':['accuracy', mean_pred]}
          }

# Do the training etc...

config_filename = 'config.txt'
with open(config_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(config))
```

Greatly appreciate help with this problem as well as other approaches to saving my configuration in the best way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I saved the name of the function as a string in the config file and then extracted the function from a dictionary to use it as metrics in the model. One could additionally use: `'class':['accuracy', mean_pred.__name__]` to save the name of the function as a string in the config. 
This does also work for multiple custom functions and for more keys to metrics (eg. define metrics for 'reg' like 'class' when doing regression and classification).

```py
import keras.backend as K
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)


config = {'epochs':500,
          'loss':{'class':'categorical_crossentropy'},
          'optimizer':'Adam',
          'metrics':{'class':['accuracy', 'mean_pred']}
          }


custom_metrics= {'mean_pred':mean_pred}

metrics = defaultdict(list)
for metric_type, metric_functions in config['metrics'].items():
    for function in metric_functions:
        if function in custom_metrics.keys():
            metrics[metric_type].append(custom_metrics[function])
        else:
            metrics[metric_type].append(function)

# Do the training, use metrics

config_filename = 'config.txt'
with open(config_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(config))
```